# Best practices for large array of integers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am loading a 123 MB file of unsigned integers that needs to be in memory (for fast look ups for a monte carlo simulation) in C++. Right now I have a global array but i've heard global arrays are frowned upon. What are the best practices for this?

For context, I'm doing Monte Carlo simulations on a poker game and need an array of about 30 million integers to quickly compute the winner of a poker hand. To determine the winner, you first compute the 'handranks' by doing 7 queries of the array. Then to determine the winner, you compare the 'handranks'.

```
int HR[32487834];

int get_handrank(const std::array<int,7> cards)
{
  int p = 53;
  for (const auto& c: cards)
    p = HR[p + c];
  return p; 
}

int main()
{
  // load the data
  memset(HR, 0, sizeof(HR));
  FILE * fin = fopen("handranks.dat", "rb");
  if (!fin)
    std::cout << "error when loading handranks.dat" << std::endl;
  size_t bytesread = fread(HR, sizeof(HR), 1, fin);
  fclose(fin);
  std::cout << "complete.\n\n";

  // monte carlo simulations using get_handrank() function
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<unsigned int> HR(32487834, 0);` And, when you want to pass that around between functions, pass it *by reference*: `int foo(std::vector<unsigned int> &arg) {...}`.

Comment: `const std::array<int,7>` -- Strange why you would be familiar with `std::array` and not `std::vector`.  Usually the first container class that is encountered in learning C++ is `std::string` and/or `std::vector`.

Comment: Globals are generally frowned upon because as programs get larger, it gets harder to reason about what might be affecting the global. But for a very small program that you don't expect to get much bigger... well, do what makes sense for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you ask ten C++ developers what is best practice for <X> you will be guaranteed to get at least eleven different answers. This is usually a matter of opinion, and as such wouldn't be an appropriate question for Stackoverflow.

Comment: You may not need to copy from the file to some buffer, if your system has something like `mmap`.

Comment: Unrelated, your nomenclature of variable names, specifically `bytesread`, and potential actions taken thereafter, is odd. The way you've proposed that `fread` call you'r asking to read *one* element with size equivalence of `32487834` int values (123.93 MB on a 32bit-int platform).  That function result will be either `0` or `1` ; not a byte count.

Comment: Global variables are bad when they are modified by a whole bunch of functions, as you sooner or later will be unable to figure out where a certain value came from. Global constants is a different thing, and quite ok.

Comment: Also note that the memset call in your example is unnecessary since global variables are value initialized.

Comment: Global data could actually be OK. If you are tempted to make a variable global, there are two questions to ask yourself. (1) Can I have two (or ten, or a hundred) like this one? (2) Can this be modified after initialisation? (In this case "initialisation" includes reading from file or the network or any similar thing). If the answer to both questions is "no" then it is probably OK to keep it global. I would make it local static in a function and return a `const` reference, just to be on the safe side (but I still consider this global data).

Comment: It's a fixed size known at compile time. So `std::array` would work and avoid the extra indirection of `std::vector`. It would have to be global or a singleton then. You could compute the handrang as a constexpr and make it a global `constexpr std::array<int, 32487834>`. Nothing wrong with globals for select cases, especially when they are const. PS: Do you actually need `int`? Isn't `uint8_t` or `uint16_t` enough? `constexpr std::array HR = compute_handrank();` can deduce the template parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use local variables, and pass them to functions as appropriate. This makes the program easier to reason about.
2. Use `vector` instead of an array for this large amount of data, otherwise you might cause stack overflow.
3. Modify your functions to work with `std::span` instead of a particular container, as this creates more decoupling.
4. Create a symbolic constant with a meaningful name for `32487834` instead of using it as a magic constant.

Comment: And for 4, that symbolic constant should be a `constexpr`, not a `#define`, since we're in C++ not C.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Yes, of course. Even in C, you should use an `enum` instead of a macro, as that produces better debug messages.

Answer (score 0):

Using local variables and passing them around is always a better practice than having globals IMO. It makes your algorithms more flexible. What if you need to use a different array for some reason later on? You would need to modify all the functions using the global variable. Passing around the array is a bit inconvenient and verbose I agree, but still better than the globals. We will address this problem later on.

So your first option is something like:

```
// Don't forget to receive the params as references to avoid copying
int get_handrank(const std::array<int,7>& cards, const std::array<int, 32487834>& HR)
{
  int p = 53;
  for (const auto& c: cards)
    p = HR[p + c];
  return p; 
}

int main()
{
  std::array<int, 32487834> HR{}; //zero-inits the array
  // or std::vector<int> HR{}; HR.resize(32487834) to avoid stack overflow as @MarkRansom pointed out

  FILE * fin = fopen("handranks.dat", "rb");
  if (!fin)
    std::cout << "error when loading handranks.dat" << std::endl;
  size_t bytesread = fread(HR.data(), HR.size() * sizeof(int), 1, fin);
  fclose(fin);
}
```

Second approach, even better: Use classes. You can have a simulation class, and the class can have the HR array as a const private member read and initialized in the constructor. Then `get_handrank` can be a member function and can access the member HR array:

```
class Simulation {
public: 
  int get_handrank(const std::array<int,7>& cards)
  {
    int p = 53;
    for (const auto& c: cards)
      p = HR[p + c];
    return p; 
  }

  Simulation()
    : HR{} 
    // or HR{readHRFromFileFunction()}
  {
    FILE * fin = fopen("handranks.dat", "rb");
    if (!fin)
      std::cout << "error when loading handranks.dat" << std::endl;
    size_t bytesread = fread(HR.data(), HR.size() * sizeof(int), 1, fin);
    fclose(fin);
  }

private:
  std::array<int, 32487834> HR;
  //or const std::array<int, 32487834> HR; if you use a function to init it
}
```

Comment: Very large local variables can sometimes produce a stack overflow.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes in this case you are right, but the author can use a local vector (that uses heap allocation) and the problem is solved :) - updated the code, thank you.